# How to use nodejs in internal network

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Nodejs's npm is very handy. So I decide to use it for my company's project.
But the problem comes .My company forces us to develop in a closed network , I can only access internal web site and other stuff...

So I wonder how to solve this problem, when you want to use npm, but outside network is disallowed.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank all.

Comment: You mean you want to connect to the internet and download packages from npm without using the internet?

Comment: Sort of . I want to know how to use npm in internal network easily

Answer (score 2):

The only possibility you have is to use npm on a machine which can navigate and then copy the npm modules in the development machine.

Answer (score 2):

Generally there are specific rules in the network that allow the team to do that things but still block another network sites.

How are you handling the downloading of third parties tools as Downloading google chrome, downloading an ide? Use the same system.

I guess that the system admin provide you those tools and/or enable specific rules so you can download it by yourself.

Otherwise you can download the npm package with your phone or another device with total network access and just copy it to your computer after that you must push it to the internal network repository otherwise your co workers should do the same thing to get the npm packages...

Or once you've downloaded it for the first time, point the npm package to local repository.

Comment: Yes ， I found that way ... Download in other computer and copy to working computer. It seem's that making an internal npm network is hard

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm

You will need to have the internet to download the packages initially and keep them updated as dependencies.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URLs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#urls-as-dependencies), [local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) and even [GIT URLs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies) as your dependencies in you package.json. I don't see why you couldn't create a pseudo npm in your own network with those methods and then just allow other developers to npm install the dependencies from there.